# For(typeof(IRepository<>)) in C# to vb?

Tags: vb.net, generics, structuremap

I've got a method I'm trying to translate from c# to vb, goes something like this ..

```
x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
```

VB doesn't seem to like the idea of a IRepository(Of ) ... what's the syntax on that?

Comment: Did you also replace `typeof` with `GetType`?

Comment: Ha, I thought I did, BUT now it's shut up and not giving me a build error. Thanks.  -- x.For(GetType(IRepository(Of ))).Use(GetType(Repository(Of )))

Comment: BTW, If you're trying to register the types that implement this with StructureMap, you're better of using the WithDefaultConventions syntax to auto-register these types instead of trying to catch them with a generic registry http://gist.github.com/473080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x.[For](GetType(IRepository(Of ))).Use(GetType(Repository(Of )))
```